# Why does the foreach code not see GetComponent<>?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

There is a code for the explosion of a grenade and the destruction of objects in the radius of action. For some reason, the foreach code does not see `GetComponent<Test>`

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;



public class Grenadde : MonoBehaviour {

    public float delay = 3f;
    public float radius = 50f;
    public float force = 700f;

    public GameObject explosionEffect;
    public GameObject explosionAudio;

    float countdown;
    public bool isGrabbed = false;

    
    public void Explode() {
        StartCoroutine(ExplodeWithTimer(3f));
    }

    public IEnumerator ExplodeWithTimer(float seconds) {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(seconds);


        Instantiate(explosionEffect, transform.position, transform.rotation);


        //Collider[] overlappedColliders = Physics.OverlapSphere(transform.position, radius);

       
            
        

        Collider[] colliders = Physics.OverlapSphere(transform.position, radius);

           foreach (Collider nearbyObject in colliders)
           { 
              Rigidbody rb = nearbyObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
            if (rb != null) {

                rb.AddExplosionForce(force, transform.position, radius); 
                Debug.Log(nearbyObject.name);               
            }
            
              Test test = nearbyObject.GetComponent<Test>();
                if (test != null) {                                   
                      
                            Debug.Log("PlayerHp");
                       }    
                


           }
                Destroy(gameObject);

    }



   



    //}

    void OnDrawGizmosSelected() {
        // Draw a yellow sphere at the transform's position
        Gizmos.color = new Color(1, 0, 0, .2f);
        Gizmos.DrawSphere(transform.position, radius);
    }
    

}
```

Comment: Can you provide a more complete [mcve] as well as the full error message you're receiving? Are you sure you don't want to use `nearbyObject.attachedRigidbody` instead?

Comment: What do you mean by `does not see`? Is that component on the object you collide with?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get component from a collider whereas you need to use `GetComponent` on a `GameObject` and not on the colliders themselves. This can be achieved as following:

```
foreach (Collider nearbyObject in colliders)
{ 
    Rigidbody rb = nearbyObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    if (rb != null) {
        rb.AddExplosionForce(force, transform.position, radius); 
        Debug.Log(nearbyObject.name);               
    }
        Test test = nearbyObject.gameObject.GetComponent<Test>();
        if (test != null) {                                   
            Debug.Log("PlayerHp");
    }
}
```